# Set value of Expression<Func<T>> inside a function

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression

Here is a part of complete argument validation system I've wrote which validates user's given argument:

```
public void Validate<T>(Expression<Func<T>> argExpr, bool justClean) where T : IComparable, IComparable<T>, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>
{
    var expressionBody = (MemberExpression)argExpr.Body;
    var argName = expressionBody.Member.Name;
    var value = argExpr.Compile().Invoke();
    if(!justClean)
        //check above value against invalid values and throw exception
    else
        //clean the value and MY QUESTION: set member's value
}
```

Now we need to set that expression's member value to cleaned version of given value like this:

```
Validate(() => item.ItemName, true);
```

As a result I expect `item.ItemName` has a cleaned value which was set inside `Validate` method.

Please notice that we can't simply return that value as a function result, because of my code flow.
So, is there any way to do this?

Comment: I´m not quite sure what you mean by a clean value. Do you mean you want to set the value of the provided member to its default-value? E.g. to `null` when `item.ItemName` was a string?

Comment: @HimBromBeere No. I have a method which is sanitize input to prevent xss attacks. The result is cleaned version of input argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a setter expression base on the expression that is sent to the function:

```
public static void Validate<T>(Expression<Func<T>> argExpr, bool justClean) where T : IComparable, IComparable<T>, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>
{
    var expressionBody = (MemberExpression)argExpr.Body;
    var argName = expressionBody.Member.Name;
    var value = argExpr.Compile().Invoke();
    if (!justClean)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(
            Expression.Assign(
                expressionBody,
                param
            ),
            param
        ).Compile();
        setter(default(T)); // Used default(T) as an example, can be any other T value 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: Just take care, compiling expression trees is not fast, you should find a way to reuse the results of the `Compile` method

Comment: If you found it useful don't forget to upvote and mark as answered